# How to increase the compatibility of the apk

Tags: android, compatibility

I am making an app and the apk file that I am installing on my phone(API 23) using USB is not supporting on other devices(I have shared the apk and try to install it on a device of API 25).But another apk can be installed on that device using USB which is again not supporting on my phone.So,the apk of my app is not compatible.

And one more thing,the layouts are becoming different in different devices and sometimes 2 images are overlapping in one while in another device it is completely fine.
So I want to increase the compatibility of my app. Please help me out.

My manifest.xml file:

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ankush.anthroplace.anthroplace">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".AboutUsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TestimonialActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ServicesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_services"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".FormActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: compatibility? Didn't quite get the problem . I do not think there is anything like compatibility except MIN SDK support AFAIK.

Comment: share your Manifest xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Check the API level you are targeting on your project.

If you're working with Android Studio, look on the file "build.gradle (Module: app)" and change the "minSdkVersion" attribute.

The lower the number you set on that attribute, the more compatible will be your app, but you should loose some features as well.

Answer (score 0):

try to put minimum sdk API level 19.
by targeting minimum apk level 19 your app will run on approximately more than 90% of android devices.

and compile your app with the latest build tool

you can change minimum sdk version from build.gradle file

```
   android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "profile.com.demotest"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check [Android Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) you will get better idea about choosing minimum api level